# Extjs 4 listen events for grid's selection model in controller

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, extjs4

I have a grid and controller for it.
I try listen for 'select' event for the grid.

The code is:

```
Ext.define('Icc.controller.Questionnaires', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  stores: ['Questionnaires'],

  models: ['Questionnaire'],

  views: ['QuestionnairesGrid'],

  init: function() {
      this.control({
        'mygrid > selectionmodel': {
            // do what I need here
        }
      });
  }
});
```

How it can be done correctly?

Comment: It is possible to use this: '{getSelectionModel()}': {}, but this will select all selection models for all components. I need use selection model for specific grid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to do that:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'questionnairesgrid': {
            selectionchange: this.selectionChange
        }
    });
},
```

Strange that I can listen events for selection model for the grid itself...

Comment: Its not strange, now that all events from sub-components are relayed to its owners, you can listen SelectionModel or View events directly from the grid.

Comment: @VoidMain - thanks, but that wasn't clear for me. So maybe this note will save someone's time :)